# Strange behavior with select list options when adding and removing tasks using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add and remove tasks from one select list to another. When clicked on the add role button, the tasks get added to the other list but I have this strange behavior, after clicking the remove button and removing tasks from the other select list was successful, on adding another tasks multiple tasks get added at the same time i.e the previous ones and the new ones  all get added. Please any help will be appreciated.

```css
select{
   padding:15px;
   min-height: 100px;
   border:1px solid;
   background: #000;
   color:#fff;
   }
select > option{
   padding:10px;
   }
```

```html
<select id="select-ml" multiple>
                 <option>Create tasks1</option>
                 <option>Create tasks2</option>
                 <option>Create tasks3</option>
                 <option>Create tasks4</option>
                 </select>
            
            <select id="select-ms" multiple>
            </select>
            
           <button id="btn-add-role">Add Roles</button>
           <button id="btn-remove-role">Remove Roles</button>
                                        
            <script>
            const selectedRoles = document.getElementById('select-ml');
            const addedRoles = document.getElementById('select-ms');
            const btnAddRole = document.getElementById("btn-add-role");
            const btnRemoveRole = document.getElementById("btn-remove-role");
            
            const roles = [];
            let newRoles = []; 
            let selectedOptions ;
            let options = [] ;
             
            
            btnAddRole.addEventListener("click", function(){
              getSelectedValues(selectedRoles);
            });
            
            btnRemoveRole.addEventListener("click", function(){
              removeRoles();
            });
            
            
            function getSelectedValues(select) {
              options = select && select.options;
              for (let i=0; i<options.length; i++) {
                if (options[i].selected) {
                  roles.push(options[i].value || options[i].text);
                }
              }
              dispayRoles();
             }
            
             function dispayRoles(){
               newRoles = roles.map(function(item){
                  return "<option>" + item + "</option>";
               })
               addedRoles.innerHTML = newRoles; 
               
             }
            
             function removeRoles(){ 
               addedRoles.remove(addedRoles.selectedIndex);
              
             }
             </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pizylon/zwos6f13/). The problem was the const roles=[]; which need not to be const and need to be aligned with addedRoles on removeRoles function:

```
  const selectedRoles = document.getElementById('select-ml');
 const addedRoles = document.getElementById('select-ms');
 const btnAddRole = document.getElementById("btn-add-role");
 const btnRemoveRole = document.getElementById("btn-remove-role");

        let roles = [];
        let newRoles = []; 
        let selectedOptions ;
        let options = [] ;


        btnAddRole.addEventListener("click", function(){
          getSelectedValues(selectedRoles);
        });

        btnRemoveRole.addEventListener("click", function(){
          removeRoles();
        });


        function getSelectedValues(select) {
          options = select && select.options;
          for (var i=0; i<options.length; i++) {
            if (options[i].selected) {
              roles.push(options[i].value || options[i].text);
              break;
            }
          }
          dispayRoles();
         }

         function dispayRoles(){

           newRoles = roles.map(function(item){
              return "<option>" + item + "</option>";
           })
           addedRoles.innerHTML = newRoles; 

         }

         function removeRoles(){ 

           addedRoles.remove(addedRoles.selectedIndex);

            roles=[];  
           options = addedRoles.options;
          for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) { 
                roles.push(options[i].value || options[i].text);
            }

         }
```

Comment: Your solution is close but it not working properly. When you removed other tasks and its left with one, on adding new task the remaining one task get removed

Comment: brilliant answers. Thanks alot but avoid using var use let instead

Answer (score 0):

when you remove an item from addedRoles you also need to remove the item from the original array "roles"  like:

```
function removeRoles(){ 
var item = addedRoles.selectedIndex
roles.splice(item, 1);
addedRoles.remove(addedRoles.selectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: pop will remove last element in the array not the selected one https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pop.asp